# Customize TDBNavigator buttons in C++ builder

Tags: database, delphi, c++builder

Is there a way how to add caption to a [`TDBNavigator`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TDBNavigator) button in C++ builder ?

Comment: How about you make your own set of buttons, that look however you like, and have them enable/disable, and handle the action on each click. It's about 1 minute of work. DB Navigator control is a hack for prototype app use only and shouldn't really be used in a real app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will allow you to add captions to each button in c++ builder

```
char *btntext[11] = {"First","Prior","Next","Last","Insert","Delete","Edit","Post","Cancel","Refresh","Apply"};
for(int x = 0; x < nav->ComponentCount; ++x)
    {
    TNavButton* navbutton = dynamic_cast<TNavButton *>( nav->Components[ x ] );
    if( navbutton )
        {
        navbutton->Font->Name = "Arial";
        navbutton->Font->Size = 8;
        navbutton->Caption = btntext[x];
        navbutton->Spacing = 0;
        navbutton->Layout = blGlyphTop;
        }
    }
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

here you have a full example of how to do it

http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/l/aa090203a.htm

it is written in Delphi, but the code can easily adapted to c++ builder.

Comment: please convert it c++ builder

Comment: $ iam a new in this site help me for free

Comment: here you get helped for free, but you must show some effort. Myself and other users gave you suggestions on how to do it. asking final piece of code without doing nothing is not working. Please read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: ok i understand the delphi code but i cant convert class declaration in delphi i just need this not more my freind